# How to create a blog.domainname.com on digitalocean instead of the blog being hosted on the domainname.com

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, ghost

I'm hosting my blog on digital ocean and I want to set up a home page with a blog.domainame.com to access my blog, I must be googling the incorrect stuff as I cannot find any resources on this.

I'm using nginx to host my blog with Ghost on digitalocean, any help or guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps but it's like create a duplicate website in fact.

You will need to update your site configuration

```
sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/second-domain
```

And create a symlink to this configuration

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/second-domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/second-domain
```

Next you must create a new folder in /var/www/, it will be the folder of your second domain. Update the config.js to match your second domain name and change the port.

The last step is to create a new system service.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/secondsite.service
```

This solution work with a custom installation of Ghost on Ubuntu.

I write an article which combine all the information and more details if you want to serve several Ghost blogs in one droplet. You will find all the step from scratch in case you don't have the same configuration.

[Install multiple Ghost CMS on DigitalOcean](https://medium.com/pixel-for-creative-people/install-multi-ghost-cms-on-digitalocean-85f7c73ed782)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I update my answer to add context.